# rails 5 - before_destroy - rescue exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app, I want to avoid records being deleted when they are used in associated records. For example if a business partner has documents (as sender OR receiver), it should not be destroyed and the user should get a flash message.

I use below code, yet get an exception.

```
before_destroy do |business_partner|
    if Document.where(:sender_id => business_partner).exists? ||
       Document.where(:receiver_id => business_partner).exists? ||
       Annotation.where(:sender_id => business_partner).exists?  ||
       Annotation.where(:receiver_id => business_partner).exists?
      raise "#{business_partner.name} has ongoing activity and cannot be deleted."
    end
end
```

Tried several alternatives - like `flash[:notice]` and `message:`

How should it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an exception, because you `raise` it.

You can change it to redirection somewhere with an alert:

```
redirect_to root_path, alert: "#{business_partner.name} has ongoing activity and cannot be deleted."
```

You might also want to take a look into associations, [`dependent: :restrict_with_error`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html):

> `:restrict_with_error` causes an error to be added to the owner if
>   there are any associated objects.

Comment: for `:restrict_with_error` how do I then add a `flash[:notice]`

Comment: meanwhile, found a solution in the controller. Tx.